# Affine Connections of Vector fields agreeing locally are equal

Tags: differential-geometry

If suppose X, Y and Z are Vector fields such that X and Z agree locally around a point p .

I need to prove that the Affine Connections are equal i.e $\nabla _X Y=\nabla _Z Y$.

Kindly help!

Any Hints will be appreciated.

Thanks and regards

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I don't know how to approach, I am new to the subject @CharlesHudgins

Comment: The usual trick when trying to prove that something holds locally is to use a smooth bump function. Does that give you some idea?

Comment: Actually, I am not familiar with this trick, can you suggest something where I can find such type of things@CharlesHudgins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I leave the details to you. Suppose $X$ and $Z$ agree on the neighborhood $U$ of $p$. Let $\phi$ be a bump function Such that $\phi(p) = 1$ and $\text{supp}( \phi) \subset U$. Then
\begin{align}
\nabla_X Y (p) &= 1 \cdot \nabla_X Y (p) = \phi(p) \nabla_X Y (p) = \nabla_{\phi X} Y(p) 
\\&= \nabla_{\phi Z} Y(p) = \phi(p) \nabla_Z Y(p) = 1 \cdot \nabla_Z Y(p) = \nabla_Z Y(p)
\end{align}

Comment: Seeing that $\nabla_X Y$ depends only on the value of $X$ at $p$ takes more work. For that, I think you have to work in coordinates, which you are able to do because of this proof.

Comment: What's so special about bump functions, Why do such type of function always exists, can't we just take any function? @CharlesHudgins

Comment: The fact that $\text{supp}(\phi) \subset U$ let us say that $\phi X = \phi Z$. That's why, in this case, they're helpful. What's special about them is that they're smooth. It is easy to find non-smooth functions $f$ such that $f(p) = 1$ and $\text{supp}(f) \subset U$, but the definition of the connection doesn't tell us anything about how non-smooth functions interact with it. The existence of bump functions comes from the fact that a manifold is locally diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. See [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-0-387-48101-2_13) for more on bump functions.

Comment: That's really the deal :)

Comment: Any undergraduate-level analysis text or introductory manifolds text will include a proof that bump functions (by which we mean a function $f$ such that, given a point $p$ and a neighborhood $U$ of it, $f = 1$ on some neighborhood of $p$ and $\text{supp}(f) \subset U$) exist. Generally speaking, they are useful in differential geometry because they help us prove that certain properties are local. The idea is that they let us "restrict" objects which agree on a neighborhoods to *identical* smooth objects.